# Chaining partition, keep_if etc

Tags: ruby, chaining

```
[1,2,3].partition.inject(0) do |acc, x|
  x>2  # this line is intended to be used by `partition`
  acc+=x # this line is intended to be used by `inject`
end
```

I know that I can write above stanza using different methods but this is not important here.
What I want to ask why somebody want to use `partition` (or other methods like `keep_if`, `delete_if`) at the beginning of the "chain"?
In my example, after I chained `inject` I couldn't use `partition`. I can write above stanza using `each`:

```
[1,2,3].each.inject(0) do |acc, x|
  x>2 # this line is intended to be used by `partition`
  acc+=x # this line is intended to be used by `inject`
end
```

and it will be the same, right?

I know that `x>2` will be discarded (and not used) by `partition`. Only `acc+=x` will do the job (sum all elements in this case).
I only wrote that to show my "intention": I want to use `partition` in the chain like this `[].partition.inject(0)`.
I know that above code won't work as I intended and I know that I can chain after block( `}.map` as mentioned by Neil Slater).

I wanted to know why, and when `partition` (and other methods like `keep_if`, `delete_if` etc) becomes `each` (just return elements of the array as `partition` do in the above cases).
In my example, `partition.inject`, `partition` became `each` because `partition` cannot take condition (`x>2`).
However `partition.with_index` (as mentioned by Boris Stitnicky) works (I can partition array and use index for whatever I want):

```
shuffled_array
  .partition                        
  .with_index { |element, index|    
    element > index                 
}
```

ps. This is not question about how to get sum of elements that are bigger than 2.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense here. Starting from `x > 2` which do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @BroiSatse: It makes sense if you assume the `x > 2` is intended for the `.partition` and the `acc+=x` is intended for the `inject`

Comment: @NeilSlater - Why would I assume such a thing, knowing it is not true. It might be the initial intention of the coder, which I can understand, however the machine has no idea and it makes no sense for it.

Comment: @BrosSatse: Maybe "assume" is the wrong word. You seem to understand what I was getting at.

Comment: @BroiSatse Neil was right. I edited the question and I think it's more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting situation. Looking at your code examples, you are obviously new to Ruby and perhaps also to programming. Yet you managed to ask a very difficult question that basically concerns the `Enumerator` class, one of the least publicly understood classes, especially since `Enumerator::Lazy` was introduced. To me, your question is difficult enough that I am not able to provide a comprehensive answer. Yet the remarks about your code would not fit into a comment under the OP. That's why I'm adding this non-answer.

First of all, let us notice a few awful things in your code:

**Useless lines.** In both blocks, `x>2` line is useless, because its return value is discarded.

```
[1,2,3].partition.inject(0) do |x, acc|
  x>2         # <---- return value of this line is never used
  acc+=x
end

[1,2,3].each.inject(0) do |x, acc|
  x>2         # <---- return value of this line is never used
  acc+=x
end
```

I will ignore this useless line when discussing your code examples further.

**Useless `#each` method.** It is useless to write

```
[1,2,3].each.inject(0) do |x, acc|
  acc+=x
end
```

This is enough:

```
[1,2,3].inject(0) do |x, acc|
  acc+=x
end
```

**Useless use of `#partition` method.** Instead of:

```
[1,2,3].partition.inject(0) do |x, acc|
  acc+=x
end
```

You can just write this:

```
[1,2,3].inject(0) do |x, acc|
  acc+=x
end
```

Or, as I would write it, this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].inject :+
```

But then, you ask a deep question about using `#partition` method in the enumerator mode. Having discussed the trivial newbie problems of your code, we are left with the question how exactly the enumerator-returning versions of the `#partition`, `#keep_if` etc. should be used, or rather, what are the interesting way of using them, because everyone knows that we can use them for chaining:

```
array = [ *1..6 ]
shuffled_arrray = array.shuffle     # randomly shuffles the array elements
shuffled_array
  .partition                        # partition enumerator comes into play
  .with_index { |element, index|    # method Enumerator#with_index comes into play
    element > index                 # and partitions elements into those greater
}                                   # than their index, and those smaller
```

And also like this:

```
e = partition_enumerator_of_array = array.partition
# And then, we can partition the array in many ways:
e.each &:even? # partitions into odd / even numbers
e.each { rand() > 0.5 } # partitions the array randomly
# etc.
```

An easily understood advantage is that instead of writing longer:

```
array.partition &:even?
```

You can write shorter:

```
e.each &:even?
```

But I am basically sure that enumerators provide more power to the programmer than just chaining collection methods and shortening code a little bit. Because different enumerators do very different things. Some, such as `#map!` or `#reject!`, can even modify the collection on which they operate. In this case, it is imaginable that one could combine different enumerators with the same block to do different things. This ability to vary not just the blocks, but also the enumerators to which they are passed, gives combinatorial power, which can very likely be used to make some otherwise lengthy code very concise. But I am unable to provide a very useful concrete example of this.

In sum, `Enumerator` class is here mainly for chaining, and to use chaining, programmers do not really need to undestand `Enumerator` in detail. But I suspect that the correct habits regarding the use of `Enumerator` might be as difficult to learn as, for instance, correct habits of parametrized subclassing. I suspect I have not grasped the most powerful ways to use enumerators yet.

Comment: Well... I'm not new in the both fields (Ruby and programming). I edited the question to make it more clear. Good point about `with_index`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the result `[3, 3]` is what you are looking for here - partitioning the array into smaller and larger numbers then summing each group. You seem to be confused about how you give the block "rules" to the two different methods, and have merged what should be two blocks into one.

If you need the net effects of many methods that each take a block, then you can chain *after* any block, by adding the `.method` after the close of the block like this: `}.each` or `end.each`

Also note that if you create partitions, you are probably wanting to sum over each partition separately. To do that you will need an extra link in the chain (in this case a `map`):

```
[1,2,3].partition {|x| x > 2}.map do |part|
  part.inject(0) do |acc, x|
    x + acc
  end
end
# => [3, 3]
```

(You also got the accumulator and current value wrong way around in the inject, and there is no need to assign to the accumulator, Ruby does that for you).

The `.inject` is no longer in a method chain, instead it is *inside* a block. There is no problem with blocks inside other blocks, in fact you will see this very often in Ruby code.

I have chained `.partition` and `.map` in the above example. You could also write the above like this:

```
[1,2,3].partition do
  |x| x > 2
end.map do |part|
  part.inject(0) do |acc, x|
    x + acc
  end
end
```

. . . although when chaining with short blocks, I personally find it easier to use the `{ }` syntax instead of `do   end`, especially at the start of a chain.

If it all starts to look complex, there is not usually a high cost to assigning the results of the first part of a chain to a local variable, in which case there is no chain at all.

```
parts = [1,2,3].partition {|x| x > 2}
parts.map do |part|
  part.inject(0) do |acc, x|
    x + acc
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the reversed order of `acc` and `x` and useless `acc += x`. Hard to catch them all in one pass.

Comment: As for accumulator - you are right. I am always mistaken with `each_with_object` which takes value first. I edited my post to make more clear of my intentions.